# determining user's preferred AVSpeechSynthesisVoice for a given language

Tags: ios, text-to-speech, avspeechsynthesizer

My iOS app provides `AVSpeechSynthesizer` support in multiple languages (not just the device's current language).
 In `Settings->General->Accessibility->Speech->Voices->Spanish`, the user can set a preferred voice to either **"Spanish (Spain)"** or **"Spanish (Mexico)"** (which correspond to **es-ES** and **es-MX**, respectively).
 Similarly with Portuguese (pt-PT, pt-BR), French (fr-FR, fr-CA), etc.

If one of my users wants to have my app speak a Spanish phrase, how can I determine which of the available Spanish voices the user has selected in Settings?

I tested `[AVSpeechSynthesisVoice speechVoices]` to see whether the ordering of the voices changes when user preferences changes, but the answer appeared to be no. 
`[AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:]` requires the full language-locale string, so passing in "es" gets you nil even though two Spanish voices are available by default. 
I scanned through all the keys in `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`, but there's nothing relevant there. And I've looked through the `UIAccessibility` documentation without finding what I need.

Answer (score 1):

The approach the works for me is as follows:

```
let defVoice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: NSLocale.current.languageCode)
```

I've tested in on English, of which there are many variants.  It returns the voice that the user has selected in Settings as their preferred voice for their current locale.